# How to call the method in Fragment from the Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on fragment concept here.Here the issue i am facing here was i need to call the **call** method in **Screen.java** only after giving the run time permission in **HomeScreen.java** class so i have been trying this but i cant get the right solution so Could you provide me proper solution for this.

```
 public class HomeScreen extends DrawerActivity {

public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 10; // code you want.
String[] permissions = new String[] {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("passing in home", "passing in home");
    checkPermission(Home.this);
    ctx = this;

}


private boolean checkPermission(Activity act) {

    int result;
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String p : permissions) {

        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, p);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
        } else {

        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, listPermissionsNeeded
                .toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] arg1,
        int[] grantResults) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, arg1, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)    {

        } else {

        }
        return;
    }

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    currentPosition = -1;
    super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

//Class 2

```
 public class Screen extends Fragment{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 call();
}
public void call(){
//my code
}
}
```

Comment: Are you adding your `Screen` `fragment` from `HomeScreen` `Activity`?

Comment: yes I am adding@Bob

Comment: It is not so clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `Fragment` instance from the `FragmentManager` using the `layout id`.

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container); 
// fragment_container is the id of the container layout where you had added your fragment
```

And cast it to your `Fragment` and call:

```
Screen screen = (Screen) fragment;
screen.call();
```

Comment: i am not quite sure which id you are mentioning.Thanks for reply bob@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.promotional_fragment, container,
                    false);
           
          
        
            return v;
        }

Comment: When you add a fragment in activity, you should have used an id: `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);` Pass that id.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the Fragment using tag**

```
String TAG="MyFragment";
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment, TAG)
        .commit();
```

You can invoke a method from your **activity** like this

```
MFragment fragment = (MFragment ) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
if (fragment) {
fragment.testMethod();
}
```